# Como cambiar el color del texto

Tags: python, tkinter, color, text

Hola estoy creando una interfaz grafica con tkinter y lo que pasa esque quiero crear un texto en esta interfaz pero que me cambie el color de las letras del texto y lo que me cambia de color es lo que rodea el texto
Asi lo tengo por ahora

```
miFrame3=Frame(root)
miFrame3.pack()
Creado=Label(miFrame3, text="Aqui va el texto")
Creado.config(bg="black")
Creado.pack()
```

Quisiera poner las letras en rojo, no lo que rodea a las letras en rojo, ojala entiendan mi punto

Answer (score 1):

Solamente debes de colocar la propiedad `fg` con el color que deseas dentro del `Label`

Si vas a colocarlo en rojo, tu código quedaría así:

```
miFrame3=Frame(root)
miFrame3.pack()
Creado=Label(miFrame3, text="Aqui va el texto", fg = "red")  # aquí la Modificación
Creado.config(bg="black")
Creado.pack()
```

Comment: Vaaale gracias esa es la propiedad que estaba buscando y no encontraba, ahi me funciono!!